# Expressjs cant get origin or referer

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to find out where are users coming from when the click a link which points to my site?

Lets assume I own `http://example.com` and a link (`http://example.com/foobar`) is placed on `http://example.net/path/to/subsite`. ***.net is not my site***

Now, when a visitor comes from `example.net` by clicking the link. Am I able to get the origin  somehow?

I run an webserver using express js and I dont know what am I doing wrong here.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  const origin = req.get('origin')
  const host = req.get('host')
  // Nothing here tells me the origin.
  console.log(origin, host, req.headers)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the URL which is calling your Express.JS API

```
req.headers.referer;
```

Comment: Hm, unfortunately its undefined… what could it be?

Comment: Please refer example 1 of this url: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-req-originalurl-property/
inside the callback function of app.get(), you can use "req" variable

Comment: Okay, nevermind. req.headers.referer is only undefined when the origin is https and my current dev server is not. Thank you!